# Method of finding polynomials $p$, $q$ such that $pf+qg=\gcd(f, g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

So I was looking through my old algebra book and found a problem that I can't figure out. Given polynomials $f$, $g$ in $F[x]$, $F$ being a field, find polynomials $q$, $p$ such that $pf+qg=\gcd(f, g)$.

I have got a few brute force solutions, but I was wondering if anyone can come up with a good algorithm? The fact we are working with a field makes we want to use the division algorithm or maybe the polynomial Euclidean Algorithm, but I can't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated. I'd be happy to see any fun solutions!

Comment: use the euclidean algorithm, in the exact same way as you would for integers.

Comment: Oh yeah right. Thanks!

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm in its original form only computes the $\gcd$ of $f$ and $g$. What is needed here is the *extended* Euclidean algorithm, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $F[x]$ is Euclidean, you can apply the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).